# Webview - how to detect redirecting URLs

Tags: android

I have a question on the Android webview.

Assume URL A redirects to URL B at the server side.

My android application when it tries to open URL A in webview, it automatically redirects to URL B.

If a URL is being redirected to some other url, I see both these urls
are stored in webview history. Now my webview history consists of
[URL x, URL y, .... URL A, URL B ]

On back key click from URL B webpage, webview will try to load URL A,
which again redirects to URL B.
We need to double click back key twice rapidly, to go back beyond URL
A

How do I solve this issue ? Is there a way to tell webview, not to put
redirecting URLs in history or any other options ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but if you know the basic URL information of the sites you wish to ignore, maybe you can look into the `doUpdateVisitedHistory` method for the `WebViewClient`. You might be able to do something like:

```
@Override
public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url,
                boolean isReload) {
    if ( url.contains("you.site") ) // do nothing
    else super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
}
```

Comment: default implementation of `doUpdateVisitedHistory()` is empty